# How to develop a web interface for an existing Java project?

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications

I have never worked much with web technologies like Javascript, PHP etc. But now I've got the following situation:

• I have a Java project. Some classes, a simple AWT gui, some input fields, two output fields. Nothing much. The gui uses my logic classes to process the input and displays the output in the output fields.

• For practizing some (for me new) web technology I would like create a HTML page which offers the same functionality: collect input, processing logic, display output.

My questions:

• Is this a valid approach? I mean gathering data on the HTML page, accessing Java code and displaying the results. Or would I better try to process the information only in Javascript? As I said, never done Javascript before. I don't know what's possible there.

• What technologies can I consider relevant? Javascript? ASP? PHP? JSP?

Some input would be really nice. Almost done with my CS master degree but web technologies have never been much of my interest and neither a part of my curriculum.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your approach, and some of it is opinion based.  But, I'd take my problem, look at what I had alraedy done, and convert that into a web application.

Get an IDE like Netbeans.
Use Tomcat.
Get the Hello World out of the way.
Create a JSP/HTML page that will display your data.
Use EL and JSTL.
Do a simple page that queries your data using the back end classes/servlets.  You can do this first if you want to use embed your html for testing very quickly to get the hang of things (I didn't say do that forever).
Display it.

Go from there.

READ lots.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a nice set up here to pick up Spring/JSP, since in JSP you can directly call different Java functions inside HTML to generate webpages. I would suggest you do a very basic JSP tutorial and then try to generate HTML by using your existing API to get different data (to display).

Once you have JSP down, look into Spring MVC. This is still in the Java domain and will give you better understanding about how to design web frameworks. Once you have JSP and Spring covered you can go ahead and create any web project you want using Java technology.

To learn Javascript, you will need to create handlers on the server side. These are the functions that will serve different requests your page makes through the Javascripts (from the browser). Your just need to create wrappers around your existing functions to get you started on this. For example, your API had a search function that returns a list object. Now create a handler that calls this function to serve JavaScript request for search functions and sends out HTTP response (rather returning a Java list) in the form of string, JSON etc.

Key things I found to be helpful when I was learning:

- Lots of reading (i.e. different tutorials)
- Quick design iterations. Try out the things that you learn, one at a time. I got overwhelmed when I tried to learn JSP/Spring (server side) and JavaScript/HTML/CSS (client side) all at the same time. Get the server side down first. Once you are able to generate HTMLs with right data, work on making things pretty/responsive on the client.